# How to create JSON object in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, dart

I'm working on one application in which I want to fill the registration form and pass this data to API.I tried almost all solutions but not solved this issue.

I'm getting this type of data after filling the form

```
[
{Date of Birth of the Baby: 08/01/1997},
{Gender of the baby: male}, 
{Time of Birth of the Baby: 12.00 pm}, 
{Father's Name: Nnn}, 
{Mother's Name: Hbhh}, 
{Any Extra Details?: Bnn}
]
```

and I want this type of data

```
 {
    "Date of Birth of the Baby": "08/01/1997",
    "Gender of the baby": "male",
    "Time of Birth of the Baby": "12.00 pm",
    "Father's Name": "Nnn",
    "Mother's Name": "Hbhh",
    "Any Extra Details?": "Bnn"
}
```

var fieldsData = [];
final myControllers = [];

```
 mydynamicData() {

    for (var i = 0; i <= widget.fieldData.length; i++) {
      fieldsData.add({
        widget.fieldData[i]['question'],
        myControllers[i].text != null || myControllers[i].text != ""
            ? myControllers[i].text
            : ""
      });

    }

    print("fieldsData:${fieldsData}");

  }
```

This is my method i know this issue occurred due to for loop but without for loop I'm not getting all fields data. so please help.

Answer (score 7):

Import:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

then you can use:

```
json.encode(fieldsData);
```

As you have a list of objects, it may be necessary to make a for in the list calling json.encode for each item, then encoding the result.

Comment: [
  {"Date of Birth of the Baby":"08/01/1996"},
  {"Gender of the baby":""},
  {"Time of Birth of the Baby":"12.99pm"},
  {"Father's Name":"Nnn"},
  {"Mother's Name":"Ggg"},
  {"Any Extra Details?":"Bhhh"}
  ]

it gives this type of data but I don't want curly braces  like I want only   [{ "" : "" }]

Comment: please let me know if you have any idea

Comment: you have a list of objects, you need to convert your list to a map.